# Polling json realtime data from a websocket and populate in HTML table, Data Streaming

Tags: javascript, json, html, websocket

I have a established a websocket connection and I can view the live data in json format on the console, But I can't seem to populate that data in a HTML. I'm trying to pull that data and populate it in a HTML Table format. M fairly new to websockets and json data.

Not sure if I should 1st store the data locally and then redistribute it to a HTML table or just Distribute it Live in HTML table. Please assist in pulling from console to a HTML table.

Js Code:

```
stomp.connect(headers, function(cb) {
    var json = '{"name":true,"Id":true}',
        obj = JSON.parse(json);
    var topic = stomp.subscribe('/destination', function(e) {
        createTable(json);
    }, headers);

});
//Data Conversion
function createTable(response){
    var tbl = document.getElementById("tableDiv");
    var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

    var header = tbl.createTHead();
    var headerRow = header.insertRow(0);
    var headerCell = document.createElement("th");
    headerCell.innerHTML = "Name";
    headerRow.appendChild(headerCell);
    var headerCell2 = document.createElement("th");
    headerCell2.innerHTML = "Id";
    headerRow.appendChild(headerCell2);

    JSON.parse(response).fields.forEach(function(field){
        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        var cell = document.createElement("td");
        var cell2 = document.createElement("td");
        cell.innerHTML = field.name;
        cell2.innerHTML = field.Id;
        row.appendChild(cell);
        row.appendChild(cell2);
        tblBody.appendChild(row);
    });

    tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
}
```

HTML Div

```
<table id="tableDiv"></table>
```

Please Assist and Thank you very much in Advance. I'm using Notepad++ as my IDE.

Comment: Are you having trouble receiving data from the server using WebSockets? Your table dom construction code seems to be fine. I have tested it here: http://jsfiddle.net/oufhz3q5/2/ Try logging the response from the server using `console.log` and check if you are actually receiving the data or not.

Comment: recieving data from the websocket is not a problem the issue is taking that data and populating it in a Table

Comment: Your code works fine when I pass hardcoded json `{"fields": [{"name":"n1","Id":1}, {"name":"n2","Id":2}]}` to your `createTable` function. Is your server sending response in same format each time?

Comment: yes it is sending it in the same format but i doesn't contain object names. it just creates an object with data. something like [{"name":"n1","Id":1}]

Comment: Then you need to change your code from `JSON.parse(response).fields.forEach` to simply `JSON.parse(response).forEach`

Comment: It gives me a "Uncaught TypeError"

Comment: That's odd. Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oufhz3q5/5/ I am sending the data in the same format as you mentioned and it works fine.

Comment: are you sure your response from server is wrapped in an array? This error is possible if the server is sending the data as object. In that case you don't even need to use the foreach loop.

Comment: How would i do it without a foreach loop, what do i replace it with if that's the case